# How to reset outlook 2010 options to default settings

Tags: reset, microsoft-outlook-2010

How can I reset the outlook 2010 default options that are accessed via the orange Ribbon File Tab > Options (left navi bar)?

Searching online gives many step-by-stepp instruction in creating an Outlook Profile, which lets you add email accounts, data files etc. but does not seem to reset the Outlook options.

Another popluar and more accurate search result goes along this line https://kb.wisc.edu/wiscmail/page.php?id=9357 but it does not apply to Outlook 2010.

Answer (score 5):

Follow these steps.

1. Make sure Outlook is closed
2. Then go to Control Panel and find the mail icon.
3. Show the profiles
4. Then delete the current profile
5. After that create a new profile and give it a name.

Now open Outlook and set your profile with the emails you want. In addition see more information [here](http://www.techyv.com/questions/can-anyone-tell-how-reset-outlook-2010)

Comment: Thanks, but alread tested and does not work. The outlook profile does not store application settings. The ones under Ribbon File Tab > Options seems to be considered as applicating settings.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you mean by "reset".  If you want to start Outlook with a clean set of folders, create a new PST.  If you want to start Outlook over with not only clean folders but with having to add accounts again, create a new mail profile and PST.  If you want Outlook to behave as if it's running for the first time, start it using the /firstrun command switch (it's not listed in Outlook's Help, but it was there for Outlook 2007, so I assume it's there for Outlook 2010 as well.  I can't check right now).  Finally, you can completely uninstall Outlook, delete all mail profiles, and reiinstall Outlook if you want to start completely fresh.

taken from: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-customize/how-to-reset-settings-on-outlook-2010/6db3ab52-9014-4f8a-8a14-11c5e5a6103f

Hope this helps :)

Comment: No I do not want to reinstall outlook. I just want to at best, click a button to reset to default; or at worse, delete some files here and there, start outlook and let it auto detect. But i will try the /firstrun. Thanks!

Comment: Seems to be the Microsoft way...delete all, reinstall.. I agree with you it is a pain to not just have a reset to defaults button. Haven't tried the /firstrun but I hope it helps you.

Comment: unfortunately, /firstrun is invalid.